# I am not getting home component in react website after npm run build command I am only getting Navbar and Footer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-router

I am not getting home component in home page in react website after npm run build command. After running command npm run build I got build folder and when I open html I am only getting Navbar and Footer component But When I click on home link I get everything working fine
my index.js code is

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and App component's code is

```
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import {
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import About from './components/About';
import Review from './components/Review';

function App() {


  return (

    <>

      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/review" element={<Review />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />


    </>

  );
}

export default App;
```

below is my navbar component's code

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Navbar() {
    

    
  return (

    <>
        <header className='header'>
            <nav className="navbar">
                <div className="logo"><Link to="/"><i className="fas fa-home"></i>Real-E-State</Link></div>
                <div className="menu-btn" onClick={toggleMenu}>
                <i className="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </div>
                <div id='menu' className="menu">
                    <ul className="navlink">
                        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/review">Reviews</Link></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                
            </nav>
        </header>
        
    </>
  );
}
```

I have already added `"homepage":"."` but didn't get solution
[this is what I get when opening with vs code live server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdGMY.png)

[and when I click on home link I get everything working absolutely fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxUtV.jpg)

Comment: Why do you have two routes pointing to the home. And the first path is empty. Try removing it and see if it works.

Comment: @NewUser134 No dear that routes was added by mistake while posting question that is not in actual code . I tried many times but even after I did not get solution

Comment: I have created many projects and I am facing the same issue with all of them

Answer (score 0):

When you just open the html file directly your app won't work because it's not being served up, you see a "static" non-live view of the HTML. When you run development builds with `npm start` a development server is started for you. `npm run build` only builds a production version of your app, it ***does not*** start a server for you.

See [Create-React-App Deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/)

> `npm run build` creates a `build` directory with a production build of
> your app. Set up your favorite HTTP server so that a visitor to your
> site is served `index.html`, and requests to static paths like
> `/static/js/main.<hash>.js` are served with the contents of the
> `/static/js/main.<hash>.js` file.

[Static Server](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#static-server)

> For environments using Node, the easiest way to handle this would be
> to install serve and let it handle the rest:
>
> ```
> npm install -g serve
> serve -s build
> ```
>
> The last command shown above will serve your static site on the port
> 3000. Like many of serve’s internal settings, the port can be adjusted using the -l or --listen flags:
>
> ```
> serve -s build -l 4000
> ```
>
> Run this command to get a full list of the options available:
>
> ```
> serve -h
> ```